# How to write query builder in laravel to search by timestamp

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
SELECT itemid,COUNT(itemid),itemname FROM `items` 
WHERE DATE(`save_at`) ='2015-12-16'
GROUP BY itemid
```

Anyone know how to write this sql in laravel 5 using query builder ???

this is the code i used but it didn't work for me

```
$query = DB::table('items')
->select(itemid, DB::raw('COUNT(itemid) as noitems')),itemname)
->where( DATE(`save_at`),'=', 2015-12-16)
->group_by('itemid')
->get();
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far ???

Comment: i have updated the code @ user3514160

Comment: @sasy The code you posted is rife with syntax errors.

Comment: @ ceejayoz how to write it ?? i'm stuck i think error gives by  DATE(`save_at`)  i don't know how to use that in laravel

Comment: @sasy You'd need a `DB::raw` around it, or (better) do something like `whereBetween('save_at', '2015-12-16 00:00:00', '2015-12-16 23:59:59')` (better because the `DATE()` call will have to run on every row in your database). You really should re-read the Laravel docs on database queries.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code.

```
$query = DB::table('items')
->select(itemid, DB::raw('COUNT(itemid) as noitems')),itemname)
->where( DB::raw('DATE(`save_at`)'),'=', '2015-12-16')
->groupBy('itemid')
->get();
```